# Fitting a model give error (ValueError: could not convert string to float:)

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, training-data, countvectorizer

Using Naive Bayes Alorithm

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

nb = MultinomialNB()
```

The code is working till this line but when i fit the model then it shows error.

```
nb.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Output:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'My fiance and 
I tried the place because of a Groupon.  We live in the same neighborhood 
and see the place all the time but the look of the place was never enough 
to draw us in.  There is nothing eye catching about the business front at 
all.  It\'s in a strip mall and looks old..........
```

I'm using yelp.csv dataset for natural language processing

Expected answer should be like this

```
MultinomialNB(alpha=1.0, class_prior=None, fit_prior=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because the **fit** method of **MultinomialNB** requires a matrix **X** of float values, not text as I guess you are providing.

In order to generate the right **X** matrix you need to compute all the probabilities for each class in your problem (say, good or bad, you are not specifying the classes in your problem), the probability distribution of your vocabulary, and the probabilities of your terms for each class. Once you generate the **X** matrix, you can fit it to the **MultinomialNB**   :)

Here you can get an idea about how to generate **X** (consider that this is a full tutorial on building a Multinomial Naive Bayes classifier, so there's a lot in there that you don't need as you're using sklearn):

https://towardsdatascience.com/multinomial-naive-bayes-classifier-for-text-analysis-python-8dd6825ece67